# How to click again if one click doesn't submit form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In puppeteer I am trying to submit a form, after filling the essential details I click on the submit button most of the times this is enough but sometimes this doesn't work and I have to click on the button again to proceed to next page. Is there any way I can implement this in my program?

I thought this may be possible by waiting for an event after click and if that event doesn't occur initiate click again but I don't know which even to wait for. I am sorry this maybe a noob question but I am new to JavaScript so I don't know much about the events.

```
await this.page.goto('https://www.urlwithform.com', {waitUntil: 'load'});
await genericParser.enterDetailsLabel(this.page,this.customerDetails);
await this.page.type('#txtCountry', this.depCity);
await this.page.evaluate((depCity) => {
var citySuggestions = document.querySelectorAll('div.autocomplete-suggestion');
    var newDepCity = depCity.toUpperCase();
    var cityRegex = new RegExp(newDepCity);
    citySuggestions.forEach((city) => {
    if(city.textContent.match(cityRegex)) {
        city.click();
    }
});
},this.depCity);
await this.page.waitFor(1000);
await this.page.waitFor('button');    
await this.page.click('#MainBody_IWOVID_item_1_btnCheckIn');
```

The enterDetailsLabel enters the form details, the code inside page.evaluate is more code specific to choosing the city in the form.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't publish your code.

Comment: "but sometimes this doesn't work" - this is what you need to fix

Comment: @jmargolisvt Updated my code, please cross check.

Comment: @Igor I know what to fix, I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Usage of `await this.page.waitFor(1000);` is always a sign of broken code. You should get rid of it and find another way to detect desired program state.

Comment: @Everettss that wait for is just for my visual confirmation that the details have been entered, it's not required for the execution when in headless mode

Comment: @NagarjunPrasad you are excused :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should wait for [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit). And maybe even better fire that event yourself and act on the callback. Make sure to fire it on the form element and not on an input. Watch out for invalid event though (maybe you should make a separate negative test for that)

Comment: Is there anyway I can check if the event hasn't triggered? If I can find this I can initiate a click again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have submit button enabled only after entering data to appropriate form fields?? If you had this case I can recommend to use

```
await page.click("button[type*='submit']", {delay: 1000});
```